# Recover image from button

Tags: visual-studio-2010

How can I recover/extract image from Button (BackgroundImage Property) in Visual Basic 2010 Express/Visual Studio 2010? I can not found Save As button

Comment: You can do it in javascript easily!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no feature in Visual Studio 2010/2008.
You can solve it with alt Print-Screen in Select resource windows and Paint.